# how to obtain class contents in html using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

This is my html code on which I wish to work:

```
<section id='price'>

<div class="row">
    <h4 class='col-sm-4'>Market Cap: <b><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 10.64 Crores</b></h4>
    <h4 class='col-sm-4'>Current Price: <b><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 35.35</b></h4>
    <h4 class='col-sm-4'>Book Value: <b><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 53.52</b></h4>
</div>
```

My question is how to obtain the market cap, current price, book value from "class='col-sm-4'".

Beacuse if I try:

```
print soup.row.col-sm-4.fa.fa-inr
```

it does not work. I am kind of new to python and web scraping So please patiently walk trough the process. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the labels by text and get the the [`next_element`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-element-and-previous-element):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div class="row">
        <h4 class='col-sm-4'>Market Cap: <b><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 10.64 Crores</b></h4>
        <h4 class='col-sm-4'>Current Price: <b><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 35.35</b></h4>
        <h4 class='col-sm-4'>Book Value: <b><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 53.52</b></h4>
    </div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

titles = ['Market Cap', 'Current Price', 'Book Value']
for title in titles:
    print soup.find(text=lambda x: x.startswith(title)).next_element.text
```

Prints:

```
10.64 Crores
35.35
53.52
```

To get the float value, you can simply *split by space* and get the first element:

```
price = soup.find(text=lambda x: x.startswith(title)).strip().split()[0]
print float(price)
```

---

You can also get them by a [CSS Selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for item in soup.select('section#price div.row h4.col-sm-4 b'):
    print item.text
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to get specifically the market value the code..`for item in soup.select("section#price div.row h4.col-sm-4 b i.fa.fa-inr"):
    print item.text` is not working and is producing a blank output

Comment: @Bharat yup, but I haven't suggested you to use the selector you are using. Use `section#price div.row h4.col-sm-4 b`

Comment: the output produced by your code contains all values ie. market cap, current price and book value but I only need market cap separately. How is it possible?

Comment: @Bharat got it, sure, just use `soup.select('section#price div.row h4.col-sm-4 b')[0].text`

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
>>> for x in soup.find_all("div","row"):
...     print x.text
... 

Market Cap:  10.64 Crores
Current Price:  35.35
Book Value:  53.52
```